# Using if statements with an else to validate form and redirect to a new page if form is valid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, if-statement

hi i've got this code to validate the form which works but it doesn't carry out the else statement and direct to the page if the form is valid

```js
function printpage() {
  if (!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('FIRSTNAME_FIELD'), 'First name')) return false;
  if (!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('LASTNAME_FIELD'), 'Last name')) return false;
  if (!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('ZIP_CODE_FIELD'), 'Post code')) return false;
  if (!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('EMAIL_FIELD'), 'Email')) return false;
  if (!isEmail(document.getElementById('EMAIL_FIELD'))) return false;
  if (!isDateOK(document.getElementById('LAST_SHOWROOM_VISIT_FIELD').value)) return false;
  if (document.getElementById('LAST_SHOWROOM_VISIT_FIELD').value != '') modifyDateFormat(document.getElementById('LAST_SHOWROOM_VISIT_FIELD'));
  document.getElementById('emvForm').submit();
  if (document.getElementById('LAST_SHOWROOM_VISIT_FIELD').value != '') modifyDateFormat(document.getElementById('LAST_SHOWROOM_VISIT_FIELD'));
  else {
    return true;
    var p1 = document.getElementById('SELECTED_PRODUCT_1_FIELD').value;
    window.location.href = "summary.html?" + "p1" + "=" + p1;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first statement of the `else` block is a return statement, which causes the function to terminate execution. So, the code after `return` won't execute.

Comment: i've moved the return statement to the end and it still doesnt work